# Accessing properties of a generic types

Tags: c#

Good morning,

I have 2 objects that i need to work with from a third party. These objects are almost identical (at least the part i need to access are. Currently i have separate methods to handle each object and i would like to see, with the help of you kind folk, if i can convert this into a generics that can handle both objects.

```
public static ObjectOut Method1(Object1 obj1)
{
   if (obj1.ErrorCode == 0)
   {
      //do something
   }
}

public static ObjectOut Method2(Object1 obj2)
{
   if (obj2.ErrorCode == 0)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

If i convert this into a single generic method, how would i access the "ErrorCode" property of the object? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do they have any similar parent ... like an interface or abstract base class?

Comment: That would only work if both objects get the `ErrorCode` from a common ancestor or interface.  I'm guessing they don't in which case two methods is a better option IMHO.  You could pull any duplicated code in those methods out into a 3rd method that both call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both types of object have a common supertype, you don't even need generics:

```
public static ObjectOut Method(ICommonInterfaceWithErrorCodeProperty obj)
{
    if (obj.ErrorCode == 0)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If the properties just happen to have the same name, you can refactor your code such that "common code" is in a separate method. I'll give you two examples:

1. `DoSomething` is a big common block.
2. `DoSomething` needs to access properties of your objects.

In the first case, you can just extract `DoSomething`:

```
public static ObjectOut Method1(Object1 obj1)
{
   if (obj1.ErrorCode == 0)
   {
      return DoSomething();
   }
}

public static ObjectOut Method2(Object1 obj2)
{
   if (obj2.ErrorCode == 0)
   {
      return DoSomething();
   }
}

public static ObjectOut DoSomething() { ... }
```

In the second case, you extract all the values you need and pass them to your common method:

```
public static ObjectOut Method1(Object1 obj1)
{
     return Method(obj1.ErrorCode);
}

public static ObjectOut Method2(Object2 obj1)
{
     return Method(obj2.ErrorCode);
}

public static ObjectOut Method(int errorCode)
{
     if (errorCode == 0)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

If you need to execute methods on your objects, you can pass lambdas to `Method`.

(And, obviously, you need to fix the fact that your methods don't return anything if the error code is non-zero. But I guess the compiler already told you that.)

Answer (score 0):

If they have any similar parent ... like an interface or abstract base class? then you can use `where` constraint saying

```
public static ObjectOut Method1<T>(T obj1) where T : IBaseObject
{
   if (obj1.ErrorCode == 0)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

If not, then you will have to cast it and access accordingly like

```
public static ObjectOut Method1<T>(T obj1)
{
   if(obj1 is Object1)
  {
   if (((Object1)obj1).ErrorCode == 0)
   {
      //do something
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: And in that case a non-generic method that accepts an `IBaseObject` should work just as well.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, yes true but thee is no other way to know if the T is of that object before acessing the property unless you are casting to it

Comment: My comment was related to your first code sample (I hadn't seen your edit). But the second sample can also be replaced by a non-generic method (one that accepts an `object`).

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you need them to have a parent (class or interface) with the `ErrorCode` defined. If you do, you could do a generic helper class such as :

```
public static class MyHelperClass<T> where T : TheCommonParent
{
    public static ObjectOut Method(T obj)
    {
       if (obj.ErrorCode == 0)
       {
          //do something
       }
    }
}
```

If you want your ObjectOut to be different, you might need to have a 2nd generic type in the class definition, but there is not enough information based on your question to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

i assume the 2 classes don't have a common base class / interface that holds all needed members...

what you can do is write a wrapper around those 2 objects that exposes all needed members and internally hands everything down to the object you are currently handling

something like

```
public class wrapper {
   private ClassA objA;
   private ClassB objB;
   public wrapper(ClassA obj)
   {
      objA=obj;
   }

   public wrapper(ClassB obj)
   {
      objB=obj;
   }

   public int? Property1 
   { 
      get 
      { 
         return objA?.Property1 ?? objB?.Property1; 
      } 
   } 
}
```