# Accessing property of a generic argument

Tags: c#

I want to create a method with generic argument person.  person can be either Man or Woman but they are just a class not inheriting from any base.  VS tells me that there is no definition for Age in T.

```
public class Man
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Man Name";
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

public class Woman
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Woman Name";
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
    public string Person<T>(T person)
    {
        return person.Age;
    };
}
```

I've search and found some solutions [Accessing properties of a generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637735/accessing-properties-of-a-generic-types) and it seems like I have to create 2 overloading methods.   As they both do the same thing, is there anyway to tell VS that T has a property Age ?

Edit: I cannot change the classes Man & Woman.  I'm writing the Person class.

Thanks.

Edit: Based on @Panagiotis Kanavos suggestions in the answer below, I tried the following and it worked.  I am now able to assign the 2 different classes' properties to the same variable (_age) and continue processing using 1 class and 1 set of logic without using generic type.  I will try this in my actual program.  Thanks very much.

```
public class People
{
    public void Person(object person)
    {
        int? _age = 0;
        switch (person.GetType().ToString())
        {
            case "Man":
                var man = person as Man;
                _age = man?.Age;
                break;
            case "Woman":
                var woman = person as Woman;
                _age = woman?.Age;
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(_age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics *remove* the need for overloading. You have to use a base class or interface and specify it as a type constraint. The compiler needs to know what members are available at compile time

Comment: I've updated the question: I cannot change the classes Man & Woman.  I'm writing the Person class.

Comment: You can't use generics then. You'll have to use dynamics or reflection. Why can't you change the classes though? What do the *real* classes look like?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assumed Y (Generics) are the solution. When that failed, you asked about Y (generics) not the *actual* problem X. What is the *actual* problem, actual classes and actual constraints?

Comment: The original problem is that there are 2 classes with exactly the same properties.  And the same processing are required in 2 different places.  I just want to write a function to put all these logic there.  However, they are independent classes without referring to abstract class or interface.

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned they aren't the same or even equivalent properties. `string Person<T>(T person)` can easily accept `int` or `string` as a type argument.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks, I understand better now.  THere must be some commonalities between the classes, other than they look similar.  They must either inherit from some abstract classes or implement a common interface.  My classes are totally independent despite having exactly the same internal.  So generic is not applicable.

Comment: That's why you need to explain the *actual* problem, not what you think the relevant parts are. There are a *lot* of ways to solve this, depending on what the code does, how much code there is, whether you can afford runtime failures

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  The example is the problem.  I just changed the class and property names. The People class logic is more than that but basically read some data from the properties and return it.  I understand now that generic won't work for this case.  I originally misunderstood generic and the answers here help me understand.

Comment: What does `read some data and return it` mean? If you use eg EF Core to read data from a database you *can* return objects in the shape you want, no matter the table's schema. You can use anonymous types and eg LINQ's Select to map items in any container to a common shape

Comment: I meant to extract the info from the class.  I've updated the question with answer, using your suggestion. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to know what the *actual* problem is, and what the actual types look like. Generics can't be used if the classes have no common type. The compiler needs to be able to check if `person.Age` is valid at compile time. If you pass the wrong type you get a compilation error. This is done by using type constraints that tell the compiler that `T` implements a specific interface or inherits from a specific type.

If the classes can't be modified, you'd have to use reflection, dynamics or pattern matching to check for the existence of the method and call it. You'd also have to handle error cases.

**Pattern Matching**

Using patter matching, you can write :

```
public class People
{
    public string Person(object person)
    {
        return switch (person) 
        {
            Man m=>m.Age?.ToString(),
            Woman w=>w.Age?.ToString(),
            _ => ""
        };
    };
}
```

This method returns an empty string if an unknown type is used. The code could be modified to throw an exception, eg :

```
public string Person(object person)
{
    return switch (person) 
    {
        Man m=>m.Age?.ToString(),
        Woman w=>w.Age?.ToString(),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected type",nameof(person));
    };
};
```

There's no reason to make this method generic. Without type constraints, the only methods that can be called are those provided by `System.Object`.

**Extension Methods**

You can create an extension method for each concrete type that can be called as if it was an actual instance method. The advantage is that the compiler itself will complain if the wrong type is used :

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static string Person(dynamicMan person)
    {
        return person.Age?.ToString();
    }

    public static string Person(this Woman person)
    {
        return person.Age?.ToString()
    };
}
```

**Dynamic typing**

Using `dynamic` would allow the code to compile but would result in runtime exceptions if the method is missing. Dynamic typing is more expensive too.

```
public string Person(dynamic person)
{       
    return m.Age?.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I give it a try.

Comment: You should explain what the actual problem is. It's not `two classes with the same properties`. If the common logic is long and complex you may need more than just pattern matching. Another option would be to use extension methods instead of pattern matching. Yes, the method *code* would be repeated, but wrong types would be caught at compile time

Comment: The problem is just that.  2 classes with the same properties and I need to write some logic which are exactly the same to process it (ie to manipulate the contents to return a result).  As you have explained, generic is not going to work as they only look similar but did not implement a common interface or inherit an abstract class, so they are totally independent and I cannot use generic. 
I saw your suggestion and I think it might work.  So later, I give it a try,  Thanks very much for that.

Comment: Your suggestion worked.  I've updated my question with answer.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an interface, or a base class, to your classes and restrict your generic type to this type:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get;  } 
    int? Age { get; }
}
public class Man : IPerson{...}
public class Woman : IPerson{...}
public string Person<T>(T person) where T : IPerson
{
        return person.Age;
};
```

This will of course make your Person class & method completely unnecessary if you are not doing anything more complex, since you can just do:

```
IPerson p = new Man();
var age = p.Age;
```

or write a method that just takes a IPerson parameter directly.

You can also let the caller define how get some parameter by injecting a delegate, i.e. `Func<T, int> getAge`. But again, for such a trivial example you are just making things more complicated for no actual gain.

Comment: I apologise as I didn't state in the question that I cannot change the classes Man and Woman.  I am writing the People class.  I've edited the question.

Comment: @EBDS Then you need to actually describe what it is you are trying to do, since you are asking the compiler to ensure "I want to take any kind of object, and this object must have a Age-property". The compiler is right to refuse this since the requirements are mutually exlusive. You could use reflection, but if reflection is the answer, you are *probably* asking the wrong question.

Comment: The original problem is that there are 2 classes with exactly the same properties.  And the same processing are required in 2 different places.  I just want to write a function to put all these logic there.  However, they are independent classes without referring to abstract class or interface.  

Having read through the solution and explanation, I think I have to live with the situation.  The 2 classes were given to me and I cannot change it.  I have to write some logic to process it and the logic are the same.